# SQL: Retrieving Unique ID with Multiple Attributes

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Ok, I had trouble describing this.  I have:

```
material table (materialID, material, etc...)
ThicknessRange table (ThicknessRangeID, ThicknessRange)
MaterialThicknessRange table (MaterialID, ThicknessRangeID)
```

I am trying to retrieve all MaterialID's from the MaterialThicknessRange table that fit all required ThicknessRangeID's.

For example, any `MaterialID with ThicknessRangeID 1 AND ThicknessRangeID 2`, etc with a variable number of ThicknessRangeID's (selected from checkboxes by the user).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide some sample table values please?

Comment: ProductID:2 Product          Description       Active
2   PORON® 4701-30   Test Description   Y

Comment: What are you using for your front end?  Web form, desktop application?  What language?

Comment: /*Products*/
ProductID: 1
Product: PORON XRD
Description: Test
Active: Y

ProductID: 2
Product: PORON ABC
Description: Test 2
Active: N

/*Thickness Ranges*/
ThicknessRangeID: 1
ThicknessRange: .015-.1

ThicknessRangeID: 2
ThicknessRange: .11-.25

ThicknessRangeID: 3
ThicknessRange: .26-1.0

/*Product Thickness Ranges*/
ProductID:1
ThicknessRangeID:1

ProductID: 1
ThicknessRangeID: 3

ProductID: 2
ThicknessRangeID: 2

ProductID: 2
ThicknessRangeID: 3

Looking for all products which match ThicknessRangeID 2 and ThicknessRangeID 3.  In this case PORON ABC (Product 2) does meet this

Comment: ASP.NET, C# calling SQL Server 2005 in a Web Based Application

Comment: Not the final version but a testing version: [link](http://www.rogerscorp.com/hpf/poron/industrial/msg/)

Answer (score 0):

Are you guaranteed to have only one entry in the MaterialThicknessRange table for a given Material/ThicknessRange combination?

```
SELECT MaterialID, COUNT(MaterialID) As NumMaterialThicknesses
FROM MaterialThicknessRange
WHERE ThicknessRangeID IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY MaterialID
HAVING COUNT(MaterialID) > 1
```

Comment: Did you try the query? Should give you the results you want. The only thing that sucks about using IN is that you can't pass it a named parameter, so you need to use a dynamic sql string or create a stored procedure that will take a string of ids as a parameter and parse it into the query (like mslliviu mentions). If you use dynamic strings [e.g. "SELECT * FROM table WHERE x IN (" + myVal + ")"] you need to be careful about sql injection. Don't just blindly accept id values from the app, validate that they are integers first.

Comment: Yes, the query worked as expected.  Thanks so much for your assistance.  Yes, I do additional checks for int values to be sure they are valid to protect against injection.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using something like this

```
select MaterialID from MaterialThicknessRange MTR inner join 
 dbo.TransformCSVToTable('1,2,15') IDs on  MTR.ThiknessRangeID = IDs.ID
```

where dbo.TransformCSVToTable is a user defined function to transform a csv string to a one column table. Bellow is one sample of such function

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_IntegerParameterListFromString] 
(   
@IntegerParameterList varchar(max)
)
RETURNS @result TABLE (IntegerID int)
AS
begin
declare @temp table (IntegerID int)
declare @s varchar(max), @s1 varchar(10)

declare @len int
set @len =len(@IntegerParameterList)
set @s = @IntegerParameterList

if (right(@s,1)<>',') set @s = @s +','


while @s<>''
begin
    set @s1 = substring(@s,1,charindex(',',@s)-1)
    if (isnumeric(@s1)= 1)
        insert @result (IntegerID) Values ( Cast(@s1 as int))
if (CHARINDEX(',',@s)>0)
    begin
        set @s = substring (@s, charindex(',',@s)+1, @Len)
    end
    else
    begin
        if isnumeric(@s) = 1
            insert @result (IntegerID) Values ( Cast(@s as int))
        set @s = ''
    end
end
return
```

end